# What is wrong with the following switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm experimenting with switch statements in Java and I've written the following program that prints out the corresponding number of the day of the week. I'm having trouble debugging the program. Here it is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your day of the week: ");
    scan.next();

    switch(str) {
        case "Monday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 1");
            break;
        case "Tuesday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 2");
            break;
        case "Wednesday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 3");
            break;
        case "Thursday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 4");
            break;
        case "Friday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 5");
            break;
        case "Saturday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 6");
            break;
        case "Sunday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 7");
            break;
            default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week");

    }
}
```

}

The error states that "str my not have been initialized". However, when I try manipulating this and initializing `str` like this:

```
String str = "Monday";
```

I end up getting the same output every time:

```
The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you so much!

Comment: It's a warning, and it says "str my not have been initialized" because, if you look closely, you didn't initialize (set the value of) `str`. Did you forget `str = scan.next()`? If you set the value as `String str = "Monday";` then of course you won't get the warning and you get the same result because the input is always `"Monday"`.

Comment: You invoke `Scanner#next`, but don't store the result in a variable. I expect you want `str = scan.next();`, or even `str = scan.nextLine();`

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it! Simple mistake, but really important. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The code should be something like would work. Initial local variable value and assignment from the scan object.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = null; // initialisation

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your day of the week: ");
    str = scan.next(); //assignment

    switch(str) {
        case "Monday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 1");
            break;
        case "Tuesday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 2");
            break;
        case "Wednesday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 3");
            break;
        case "Thursday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 4");
            break;
        case "Friday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 5");
            break;
        case "Saturday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 6");
            break;
        case "Sunday":
            System.out.println("The number corresponding to your chosen day is: 7");
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid day of the week");

    }
}
```

Comment: You should add at least a little explanation. Indicate what you fixed in the code specifically and why.

Comment: The edit was in progress. Anyways thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Fixed by doing str = scan.next();